# Can VSCode show file content in columns?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any plugin can make one file shown in multiple columns like following

[image]

VSCode itself doesn't have such feature, can no proper plugin was found.

Comment: Another option would be to use Vim for this use case: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/View_text_file_in_two_columns